# using vue.js I can't seem to get the picture to show up on first click

Tags: javascript, vue.js, async-await

So I was watching a tutorial from 2 years ago to get my feet wet with the Marvel API and vue.js. The goal of the code is to call the API and make a list of the Marvel characters that are returned. When I click on each link the Character's name, description and pic should show. However, it never works on the first try. For instance in the picture provided. I expect it to show and work every time.

```
characters vue (plural)
<template >
    <div>
        <div class="card-container">
            <div class="card" v-for="character in characters" v-bind:key="character.name">
                <h3>{{character.name}} </h3>
                <router-link :to="{name: 'character', params: {id: character.id} }"> 
                    <button type="button" name="viewButton" class="btn-view">View</button>
                </router-link>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
  </template>

<script>
import {mapState} from 'vuex'
import axios from 'axios'

export default {
    name: 'Characters',
    mounted(){                
        this.$store.dispatch('getCharacters')
        console.log(this.characters)
    },  
    
    computed:{
        ...mapState({
            characters: state => state.characters
        })
    },

    methods:{
    }
}
</script>

<style lang="css">
</style>
```

then we have character single view

```
character vue(singular)
<template>
    <div>
        <div class="flex-container">
            <div class="flex" v-for="char in character" v-bind:key='char.name'>
                <h3>
                    {{char.name}}
                </h3>
                <p>
                    {{char.description}}
                </p>
            </div>
            <div class="flex2">
                <img class="char-img" :src="url" >
            </div>
        </div>      
    </div>
</template>
<script>
import {mapState} from 'vuex'
export default {
    name:'Character',
    data(){
        return {
            url:'',
            size:'landscape_incredible.jpg',
        }       
    },
    computed: {
        ...mapState({
            character: state => state.character,
            preUrl: state => state.url
        })
    },
    mounted(){
        this.$store.dispatch('getCharacter', this.$route.params.id)
        this.getImage()
    },
    methods: {
        getImage(){
            this.url = `${this.preUrl}${this.size}`
        }
    }    
}
</script>
<style>
    
</style>
```

and the main js

```
main.js
async getCharacters(state){
      state.characters = []
      
      try{
        const res = await fetch(`http://gateway.marvel.com/v1/public/characters?apikey=${public_key}`)
        const data = await res.json()
          data.data.results.forEach(item => {
          state.characters.push(item)
          })
          return data
        }catch(err){
          console.log(err)
        }
    },
  
    async getCharacter(state, id){
        state.character = []        
        try{
          const res = await fetch(`http://gateway.marvel.com/v1/public/characters/${id}?apikey=${public_key}`)
          const data = await res.json()
          data.data.results.forEach(item => {
            state.character.push(item)
            state.url = `${item.thumbnail.path}/`
          })
          return data
        } catch(error){
           console.log(error)
        }
    }// end getCharacter singular

  },

  actions: {
    getCharacters: context => {
      context.commit('getCharacters')
    },

    getCharacter(context, id){
        context.commit('getCharacter',id)
    }
```

Comment: Can you please elaborate the issue that you facing and the expected outcome?

Comment: @SowmyadharGourishetty the picture basically explains the situation. when you first load then click a name the picture won't load originally. I click home and same person it works, then i click home and a new person it shows the wrong picture what else you need me to explain?

Comment: I am asking because to me the pic made a lot of sense so I am trying to figure out what else or how else am I am to explain. I expect every time I click on the link for the picture to be accurate every time.

Comment: Can you also please show us the vue components code that you have implemented to show the pictures

Comment: Well there goes my picture lol so much for the edit lol

Comment: @SowmyadharGourishetty I added it :)

Comment: so is there an answer to this somewhere else?